# Is it possible to use diff in an Android app?

Tags: android, diff

Is diff in any way, shape, or form included in Android such that it can be called from an Android app?  Or do I just have to use one of the java packages available (e.g. [Generate formatted diff output in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319479/generate-formatted-diff-output-in-java)).

Basically what I'm trying to do is open an xml file, and then immediately output an xml file to ensure that my app isn't screwing anything up with its import/export process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't assume it was available, I'd use one of the java implementations.  I doubt you can even reliably shell out or anything without jailbreaking.

Comment: While not exactly what I was asking for (since what I was asking for likely doesn't exist), it is a viable workaround.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at this post: [Where are my Android app's data files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053252/where-are-my-android-apps-data-files)

You could try reading in the XML, then writing it out to a new file, then using adb to pull both files and do the diff on your computer (not on the device).

Comment: That would work for testing, but I want this to be something which is automated and happens whenever anyone runs the app (and if it detects differences, have it pop up a message which brings up the option of emailing me the failing file so that I can find and remedy the bugs.

Comment: If you don't care about a nice diff view, you could write the output file, then open both as inputStreams, and compare byte-by-byte to see if they're exactly the same.

Comment: or just take an md5 hash of the files and if they differ send the file back to HQ